# Change of variable formula when integrand involves partial derivatives

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, partial-derivative, change-of-variable

A well known change of variable theorem of integral calculus says the following.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a diffeomorphism.
Then
\begin{eqnarray}\tag{1}
\int\limits_{Y} f(y_1,y_2) dy_1 dy_2=\int\limits_{X} f(\phi(x_1,x_2)) \left|J_{\phi}(x_1,x_2)\right| dx_1 dx_2,
\end{eqnarray}
where $J_{\phi}$ denotes the  Jacobian matrix of $\phi.$

What is the corresponding change of variable formula if the integrand involves derivatives.
More precisely, for $f \in C^1$ what is the change of variable formula if the integrand is
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{Y} \left(\partial_1f(y_1,y_2)+\partial_2f(y_1,y_2)\right) dy_1 dy_2=\int\limits_{X} \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot dx_1 dx_2.
\end{eqnarray}
How to prove the change of variable formula for such integrand using the change of formula (1) ?

Comment: Try to compute the partial derivative of y_1 or y_2 in terms of x_1 and x_2 applying the chain rule. That would give you the change of variable. Finally you should multiply by |J|.

Comment: Good question. I always get confused with this kind of computations.

Comment: Unless there is something I am missing, the answer is straight forward: With $F(y_1,y_2)=\partial_1f(y_1,y_2)+\partial_2f(y_1,y_2)$, $$\int_{\phi(X)}F(\mathbf{y})\,d\mathbf{y}=\int_X F(\phi(\mathbf{x})|J_\phi(\mathbf{x})|\,d\mathbf{x}=\int_X \Big((\partial_1f)(\phi(\mathbf{x})) +(\partial_2f)(\phi(\mathbf{x}))\Big)|J_\phi(\mathbf{x})|\,d\mathbf{x}$$ The $\phi$ has nothing to do with $f$.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz as far as I know, it does not work that way

Comment: @Sameera: You may be confusing the change of variables through diffeomorphisms with the Stokes theorem: $\int_S \operatorname{div}(f_1,f_2)\,d\mathbf{x}=\int_{\partial S}(f_1,f_2)\cdot \mathbf{n}\,d\sigma$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: ciao mio stimato amico, I just would like to ask what is confusing about this question. Cheers!

Comment: I mean, the theory is clear and precise, as you rightfully point out, but in practice one can be confused. Suppose , to make up an example, suppose to have an integral such as $\iint \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x}\, dxdy, $ where $f$ is some explicit, or semi-explicit, expression. You change variables, say $x=\phi(X, Y), y=\psi(X, Y)$. How does the integral change? While it is clear that $dxdy=|J|dXdY$, what happens to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$? On computations like this, I usually need to slow down a moment, otherwise I end up getting confused.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I guess is just a matter of good notation, that is, in  $\frac{\partial}{\partial_x}f(\Phi1(u,v).\Psi(u,v))$ it seems clear -at least to me- that the partial derivative with respect to $x$ of the function $f$ is being evaluated at the point $(x,y)=(\Phi1(u,v).\Psi(u,v))$; in $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(\Phi1(u,v).\Psi(u,v))$ we are calculating the partial derivative with respect to $u$ of the map $(u,v)\mapsto f(\Phi(u,v),\Psi(u,v))$. I agree that sometimes, things become a little burry. But in the case of the OP's question, the calculation is just as in my comment.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: The OP's response to my comment however make me feel that there is some confusion on his/her part. But , who knows, I might be the one with the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One element of confusion is coming from a somewhat imprecise notation.
Writing $\partial_1 f$ is asking for trouble when you invoke a change of variables. If instead you write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1}$
or $\partial_{y_1} f$ this removes (in principle) any ambiguity.
For example if $f(y_1,y_2)=y_1^2 y_2$ then (omitting domains)
$$\int \partial_{y_1} f (y_1,y_2) dy_1\, dy_2 =\int 2 y_1 y_2 \, dy_1\, dy_2 $$
when changing variables gives
$$ 
 \int \partial_{y_1}f\circ \phi(x_1,x_2) \; J(\phi)\; dx_1 dx_2 = \int 2\phi_1(x_1,x_2)\phi_2(x_1,x_2)\; J(\phi)\;dx_1 dx_2$$

Answer (score 3):

I think that you just has a confusion with the notation, by example we will have that

$$
\int_A \partial _1 f(x,y)d(x,y)=\int_{\phi ^{-1}(A)}(\partial _1f\circ \phi)(x,y)|\det [\partial \phi(x,y)]|d(x,y)  \tag1
$$

for some diffeomorphism $\phi$. Here $\partial_1 f$ is a function as any other (and above I used the symbol $\partial$ alone without subscript to denote the Fréchet derivative of the function $\phi$). Note that $\partial _1 f\circ \phi $ and $\partial _1(f\circ \phi )$ are two different things, the first one is the composition of the functions $\partial _1 f$ and $\phi $, but the second is the derivative respect to the first argument of the function $f\circ \phi $. Maybe something like that was your source of confusion.

Also observe that I used the notation $(h\circ l)(x)$ instead of $h(l(x))$, the first is preferably in almost all situations by many reasons, one of them is the enhanced clarity in it meaning because there is a separation between the notation for functions and it arguments.

Also note that the notation $\partial_1$ is more clear and simple than something like $\partial_x$: just observe that in (1) I didn't needed to denote in the second integral the arguments using different letters, however if I would used $\partial_x$ instead then I would need to change the name of the argument $x$ to something else because otherwise will be confusing, but it will be confusing anyway because then there is no argument $x$ to know what is the partial derivative that you took!